# select items in multiselect when editing in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I need set selected items when editing object, if someone could give me an idea how i could use spring boot with thymeleaf.I attach an image of the graphical interface that I have developed, and it is in the Reference column where I need to load the items that have been selected when I want to edit the object

[image: see image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this `<option   th:selected="${it.getuaguas().contains(matriz)}" th:each="matriz:${it.parametro.criterio}"  th:value="${matriz.id}" th:text="${matriz.descripcion}"></option>`